# What is an Obsolete reference in java

Tags: java

> I'm reading the Effective Java book and its saying that eliminating obsolete reference is one of best way to avoid memory leaks. according to the below program, by doing -> elements[size] = null; its eliminating obsolete references in that program. 
>   My problem here what is the advantage of doing elements[size] = null;. Any other program can use that freed memory location? Or is it garbage collected?
>   According to my understanding the array is already allocated the memory for its size. Even we do elements[size] = null;  anyone can't use that freed memory location until you do elements = null;. Please someone tell me what is advantage of doing elements[size] = null; here.

```
public Object pop() {
    if (size == 0)
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    Object result = elements[--size];
    elements[size] = null; // Eliminate obsolete reference
    return result;
}
```

Comment: "*[...] to the below program [...]*" - what program? --- To your question: arrays do not store data in-place (at least, object-arrays don't). They store references to objects. By nulling the array entry (i.e. throwing the reference to the object away), the object may become eliglble for garbage collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My problem here what is the advantage of doing elements[size] = null;.

Here obsolete references refer to object references not required any longer for the program.
You want that unnecessary objects to be free to consume only memory that your program need. Generally it is done for the good working of the current application.

> Any other program can use that freed memory location?

Theoretically yes but it also depends on the JVM memory options used. You don't generally focus on it.

`elements[size] = null` and     `elements = null;` don't have at all the same intention and the same effects.

In the context of the book, `elements` is a structural intern of a class.
The idea is that some elements of the array may be stale and not required any longer after some removal operations.

The first one (`elements[size] = null`) will make the object of the array element located at the `size` index to be eligible to be GC if no other objects reference .
But the second one (`elements = null`) is much more. It will make all elements of the array to be eligible to be GC if no other objects reference it.

Comment: Thinking about it, isn't "size" an invalid index in the first place?

Comment: Typically size-1 would be the last valid index?!

Comment: Ah ok. `elements[--size];` is done before. so `size` refers to the last element.

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases we have to distinguish:

1. The outer object is "teared down" somehow, so it closes any open resource and also "voluntarily" releases all objects it had referred to. This s simply the explicit way of telling the jvm that the corresponding refence is "gone". You make it easier for the gc to understand: the corresponding object is eligible for garbage collection. Of course, that only has that effect if there are no other references to the same object elsewhere. And beyond: doing so isn't really required, the jvm/gc must of course be able to detect any eligible object all by itself.
2. But nullifying makes sense for refences that exist for longer periods of time, pointing to different objects over that time span. Like a container, such as the stack class in the underlying example. A container *must* forget about objects it referenced to when they get "removed". Otherwise you create a memory leak!

Comment: I don't follow. Nullifying a single array slot doesn't help with that. Either the whole array is alive, or it is not.

Comment: By doing  elements[size] = null; only the value of the elements[size] is setting into null. but the corresponding memory location of that element will be kept as allocated until the program ends or until we set elements  = null right?

Comment: "elements" only contains references to other objects. By setting a specific slot to null, you don't change the size of the array.

Comment: "the jvm/gc must of course be able to detect any eligible object all by itself": not in the `pop()` example. The instance referenced by `elements[size]` can't be reclaimed without the nulling.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff I enhanced the answer accordingly to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

### What happens here?

Let's imagine, `elements` is a 20-elements `Object` array (`elements = new Object[20];`), and has been filled with 18 `BigInteger` instances, the remaining two places being null.

So the heap now contains 18 `BigInteger` instances and a 20-elements `Object[]` array. The garbage collector won't reclaim any of these instances, and that's okay as you'll most probably use them later (via the `pop()` method).

Now you call the `pop()` method to get the `BigInteger` most recently added to the array. Let's assume you just want to print it and then forget it, so in your overall application that number isn't needed any more, and you'd expect the garbage collector to reclaim it. But that won't happen unless you do the null assignment

```
elements[size] = null; // Eliminate obsolete reference
```

### Why that?

As long as you store the reference to an object in some accessible place, the garbage collector believes that you'll still need the object later.

As long as `elements[17]` still refers to the `BigInteger`, it can potentially be accessed by your program, so it can't be reclaimed. If `elements[17]` points to null, the `BigInteger` that used to be there isn't accessible via `elements` any more and can be reclaimed by the garbage collector (if no other part of your code still uses it).

### Conclusion

It's only worth thinking about "obsolete references" if you have a long-living storage structure that contains fat objects, and you can tell at some point in time that you won't need one of the stored objects any more. As you won't need this object any more, you can now re-assign the storage with `null`, and then the GC no longer believes you still need the object and is able to reclaim the storage space.